# Active Admin use related model fields in filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have User model and Address, SocialProfile Model. I want to show the fields of Address model like "zip", "address_line_1" in the filter section of User resource in active admin.

As Address model i want to show the fields of SocialProfile Model in same resource of User.
how can I show the fields in both drop-down and text search in active admin of belongs_to model?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses
  has_many :social_profiles
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
end

class SocialProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Filters for User resource in app/admin/user.rb**

```
filter :mobile
filter :full_name
filter :zip #to use the address model's "zip" field
filter :source #use social_profile model's "social" field
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to filter the associated models just by using

```
filter :address_zip, as: :string
filter :social_profile_mobile, as: :string
```

and it will only filter those specific fields of the associated model. I might be off on which of those attributes belong to which model, but the idea is the same.

Comment: Great!! Worked for me! 
`filter :addresses_zip, as: :string
filter :social_profiles_mobile, as: :string `

Comment: it is also working like if i am having Document model and it belongs to User and
IdentityDocument Model which belongs to Document so in Document AA Resource i can add filters like
**Document belongs_to User**                                                                        
`filter :user_mobile, as: :string`
**Document has_many IdentityDocument, where type is an attribute of IdentityDocument**                                                                                          
`filter :identity_documents_type, as: :string`